# Extract first word from a line in a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How do I get the first word from each line? Thanks to help from someone on Stack Overflow, I am working with the code below:

```
File.open("pastie.rb", "r") do |file|
  while (line = file.gets)
    next if (line[0,1] == " ")
    labwords = line.split.first
    print labwords.join(' ')
  end
end
```

It extracts the first word from each line, but it has problems with spaces.  I need help adjusting it. I need to use the `first` method, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what the `next if...` line does. Unlike a normal `if` statement, it is complete on just that line, and the following lines are not part of it (which is what your indentation is suggesting).

As for your question: Try taking out the `.join(' ')` and see what happens.

Comment: You are right. I removed the .join because I was getting a method error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
def first_words_from_file(file_name)
  lines = File.readlines(file_name).reject(&:empty?)
  lines.map do |line|
    line.split.first
  end
end

puts first_words_from_file('pastie.rb')
```

Comment: `lines = File.open(file_name, 'r') { |f| f.readlines }` is a real awkward way to read a file into an array. Use `File.readlines(file_name)` instead. It does the same thing. Don't use `next if line.empty?` in a `map` because that forces you to use `compact` after the fact. Instead, filter out the empty lines using `select` or `reject` before you use `map`.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping next to avoid *collecting* a `nil`. But I added that compact to take it out. Off-topic: Shouldn't be there a way to **skip** values?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the first word from each line from a file:

```
first_words = File.read(file_name).lines.map { |l| l.split(/\s+/).first }
```

It's pretty simple. Let's break it apart:

```
File.read(file_name)
```

Reads the entire contents of the file and returns it as a string.

```
.lines
```

Splits a string by newline characters (`\n`) and returns an array of strings. Each string represents a "line."

```
.map { |l| ... }
```

`Array#map` calls the provided block passing in each item and taking the return value of the block to build a new array. Once `Array#map` finishes it returns the array containing new values. This allows you to transform the values. In the sample block here `|l|` is the block params portion meaning we're taking one argument and we'll reference it as `l`.

```
|l| l.split(/\s+/).first
```

This is the block internal, I've gone ahead and included the block params here too for completeness. Here we split the line by `/\s+/`. This is a regular expression, the `\s` means *any whitespace* (`\t \n` and space) and the `+` following it means *one or more* so `\s+` means *one or more whitespace character* and of course, it will try to match as many consecutive whitespace characters as possible. Passing this to `String#split` will return an array of substrings that occur **between** the seperator given. Now, our separator was *one or more whitespace* so we should get everything between whitespace. If we had the string `"A list of words"` we'll get `["A", "list", "of", "words"]` after the split call. It's very useful. Finally, we call `.first` which returns the first element of an array (in this case "the first word").

Now, in Ruby, the evaluated value of the last expression in a block is automatically returned so our first word is returned and given that this block is passed to map we should get an array of the first words from a file. To demonstrate, let's take the input (assuming our file contains):

```
This is line one
And line two here
Don't forget about line three
Line four is very board
Line five is the best
It all ends with line six
```

Running this through the line above we get:

```
["This", "And", "Don't", "Line", "Line", "It"]
```

Which is the first word from each line.

Comment: This is extremely useful. Thank you. .map is still a bit confusing to me. Ill study what you have written and do more research on it.

Comment: Map is pretty simple: it just runs each element of an array through a subroutine and returns a new array with those values. Say, for example, that you wanted to multiply every value in an array by two. You could use map: `array_by_two = [1,2,3,4].map{|val| val * 2 }`. `array_by_two == [2,4,6,8]`